# How to I block advertisements for one specific app?

Tags: ads

Lately I've been getting ads for a TikTok-like app called Kwai. These ads always include girls of questionable age dancing very suggestively to the sound of very bad music.

These ads appear on many of my apps, from YouTube to Duolingo (and other language study apps), and it's very annoying to see these while I'm trying to concentrate, especially since it always comes with loud music (while I'm wearing headphones to listen to my lessons). I did manage to get rid of them on YouTube by using Vanced, but I've still got issues with the other apps I use.

I don't mind any of the other ads that show up; it's only this one I've got beef with. That being so, I'd like to know if there's any way to block all ads for this Kwai app, specifically, from showing on my apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since these objectionable ads show up in multiple apps, they are likely being mass-distributed by a large advertising provider company (such as Google).

I don't think you'll be able to successfully block ads for a single product that are distributed this way, but since the content of the ads is questionable, you can determine which ad provider is delivering questionable content, and file a report with them.  If the content being pushed is illegal in your jurisdiction, you can also involve law enforcement.

Finally, you can notify the developers of all the apps in which you see these ads and let them know about the issue.  They can then file a report with their ad providers and consider finding more suitable ad providers.  If you leave accurate reviews regarding this issue, you may be able to pressure the developers of the apps you use to find a more appropriate advertising provider or remove the advertising content altogether.  Often, you can purchase paid versions of apps that have no advertising.